# Meaning of でも in this special context from しまこうさく　まなが

Tags: meaning, translation, usage

日商工は３団体**でも**一番歴史が古く１９２２年に発足した。

(As backdrop, the 経済連、経済交友会 and 日商工 are the three largest business lobbying organizations in Japan according to the Manga. And 日商工 is the oldest.)

My question: what does でも mean here?  でも usually have three meanings:- 1) but  2) even including and 3) among other things. But でも here does not seem to fit in any of the above meanings.

Comment: I think that's two separate particles で + も.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the で and the も are analyzed separately or as one unit, でも in this sentence would emphasize the subject as the **superlative case** among the three, loosely fitting within the second usage you listed ("even including").

Sometimes it's hard to find a corresponding usage category in a J-E dictionary, which usually list only the main usages, whereas in a more comprehensive J-J dictionary you can find a closer match.